# Airflow Login Failed After Creating User

Tags: airflow

I have created an admin user using below command, and it was successfully created as I have received a message saying - *Admin user test_admin created*. I can also see a record in ab_user table (postgreSQL). However, when I try to log in with the credential (I ensured I did not type wrong credential) on Airflow WebUI, I get ERROR *Invalid Login*.

Any idea what i am doing wrong, please?

`airflow create_user -r Admin -u test_admin -f admin -l test-p test122 -e test.test@gmail.com`

Note = I have set `rbac = true` in airflow.cfg file.

Answer (score 0):

Please do following checks.

1. Check whether record inserted in the **ab_user** table in the database.
2. If yes, check whether below parameter is added in airflow configuration file under [webserver] section.

   auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth